# Kernel of sum of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was wondering if there is any relation between the kernel of the sum of 2 linear maps and the kernels of the linear maps. Also if the kernel of each linear map is finite dimensional, does that imply that the kernel of the sum also finite dimensional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much *not* the case that the sum of the kernels is contained in the kernel of the sum.  In particular: take
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad
B = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}
$$
The sum of the kernels $\ker(A) + \ker(B)$ is $\Bbb R^2$, and the kernel of $A + B$ is $\{0\}$.

What we do have, however, is that $(\ker(A) \cap \ker(B)) \subset \ker(A+B)$.

The sum of two maps with a finite dimensional kernel need not have a finite dimensional kernel.  In particular, if we take the maps $\pm\operatorname{id}$ on an infinite dimensional space, then each map has a zero-dimensional kernel, but their sum has an infinite-dimensional kernel.

Comment: thanks, I see my mistake. but i disagree that $\ker(A+B) \subset \ker(A) + \ker(B)$. say $x \in ker(A)-ker(B)$ then $(A+B)(x) \neq 0$

Comment: Okay, so you're saying then that $x \in [\ker(A) + \ker(B)] \setminus \ker(A + B)$, which is consistent with the inclusion.

Comment: $\ker(A+B)\subset\ker A+\ker B$? What if $A=I$, $B=-I$?

Comment: @Rahul... whoops

Comment: @Omnomnomnom nice use of Rahul's e.g to come up with that counter-e.g. and in my comment above i was saying that if the kernels of $A$ and $B$ don't coincide then take $x$ in the kernel of $A$ but not that of B. but your answer did help, thanks.

Comment: Again, if you take $x$ in the kernel of $A$ but not in $B$, then you have an element of $\ker(A) + \ker(B)$ that is *not* an element of $\ker(A+ B)$.  Note, however, that this does not *disprove* my statement (which Rahul's comment did disprove).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yeah you are right. my comment was completely irrelevant, my mind must not be working right